# Collapse Event using Bootstrap and AngularJS - Navbar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-routing

So I've looked though some of the questions already asked about this issue and have not been able to find a solution that works for me.

I am using Bootstrap (v 3.3.5) to create a navbar menu at the top of my site. I am also using AngularJS (v 1.4.4) and Angular-UI-Bootstrap (v 0.13.3). When the menu collapses and is shown you have to toggle the menu button in order for it to close. clicking the menu links or outside of the menu has no effect.

So I tried several solutions talked about on Stackoverflow but none of them have worked for me.  After several hours of pulling my hair out I came up with an option for closing the menu when the route changes (AngularJS $route) but my code does not seem to be doing the trick. I would love some advice.

```js
(function (Directives, undefined)
{
 app.Modules.app.directive("collaspeListener", [ function () /* AngularJS Directive */
 {
  return {
   restrict: 'A',
   link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    $('#navcollaspe').on(shown.bs.collapse, function () { /*Bootstrap collapse JS */
     console.log("shown");
     $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() { /*AngularJS $route */

      $('#navcollaspe').collapse('hide') /* Bootstrap collapse JS */
     })
    })
   }
  }
 }]);
}(app.Directives = app.Directives || {} ));
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container" collapse-listener="">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed visible-xs-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcollapse"  aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-brand"><a href="#/"><img src="assets/images/logos/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo"></img></a></div>
    <div class="navbar-text navbar-left hidden-xs"><a href="#/">Main Title</a></div>
    <div class="navbar-text navbar-left visible-xs-block "><a href="#/">Short Title</a></div>
    <div class="outside-nav">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right visible-sm-block dropdown-menu-left">
       <li ><a href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
       <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#/systems">...</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/systems">...</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/systems">...</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/systems">...</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/systems">....</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/systems">...</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/systems">...</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/systems">...</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-header">Applications</li>
         <li><a href="#/applicationsPage">...</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
       <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-header">Company</li>
         <li><a href="#/company"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> About US</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/company"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Company Blogs</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/company"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span> Contact Us</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
       <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-header">My Account</li>
      <li><a href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" aria-hidden="true"></span> Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox" aria-hidden="true"></span> Messages <span class="badge">{{ user.newMessagesCount }}</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> Settings</a></li>
         <li class="divider"></li>
         <li><a href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" aria-hidden="true"></span> Sign Out</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
   </ul>
    </div><!-- End outside-nav -->
  </div><!-- End navbar-header -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcollapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li class="active"><a href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
       <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></span> Systems<b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#/systems" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcollapse">...</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/systems">...</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/systems">...</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/systems">...</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/systems">...</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/systems">...</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/systems">....</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/systems">...</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span> Applications<b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#/applicationsPage">...</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
       <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></span> Company<b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#/company"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> About US</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/company"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Company Blogs</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/company"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span> Contact Us</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
       <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> My Account <span class="badge">{{ user.newMessagesCount }}</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" aria-hidden="true"></span> Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox" aria-hidden="true"></span> Messages <span class="badge">{{ user.newMessagesCount }}</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> Settings</a></li>
         <li class="divider"></li>
         <li><a href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" aria-hidden="true"></span> Sign Out</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div><!-- End navbar-collapse -->
 </div><!-- End Navbar Container -->
</nav><!-- End Top Navbar -->
```

Comment: Does `console.log("shown");` ever get executed? Also, you do not seem to inject `$rootScope` anywhere.

Comment: Nope it doesn't get executed. Where would I need to inject it at? I'm new to JS. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking over the code and doing some more research I was able to find a way to collapse the menu whenever a link within it was clicked.

I found a couple places where I miss spelled something, which after fixing got the code to execute the `console.log('shown')` but nothing else. So I ended up finding a great tutorial on how to properly use AngularJS and Bootstrap together using Angular-UI. The tutorial is by [Chris Sevilleja](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together).

So after adjusting my code to follow Angular-UI recommendations it works as expected. I also injected `$rootScope` based on a recomadation from [Hinrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2024590/hinrich) in the comments above. I have included the new code in hopes that it saves someone else some time and frustration. :)

```js
(function (Controllers, undefined)
{
 app.Modules.app.controller("navController", ['$scope', function ($scope)
 {
  $scope.isCollapsed = true;
 }]);

}(app.Controllers = app.Controllers || {} ));

(function (Directives, undefined)
{app.Modules.app.directive("collapseListener", ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope)
 {
  return {
   restrict: 'A',
   controller: 'navController',
   link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous, rejection) {
     if (scope.isCollapsed == false) {
     scope.isCollapsed = true;
     }
    })
   }
  }
 }]);
}(app.Directives = app.Directives || {} ));
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container" collapse-listener="">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-brand"><a href="#/"><img src="assets/images/logos/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo"></img></a></div>
    <div class="navbar-text navbar-left"><a href="#/">Full Title</a></div>
  </div><!-- End navbar-header -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" collapse="isCollapsed">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li class="active"><a href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
       <li dropdown=""><a dropdown-toggle=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></span> Systems<b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#/systems">...</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/systems">...</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/systems">...</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div><!-- End navbar-collapse -->

 </div><!-- End Navbar Container -->
</nav><!-- End Top Navbar -->
```